# ReactNative error Objects are not valid as a react child if you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

so I have an object.eg {'monday': 1, 'tuesday': 2} I am using props.getProductiveDay() to get the updated object when the user log for the day and i want to render those data in the horizontalbargraph data property but instead I got the error Objects are not valid as react child use an array instead

```
 const HorizontalBarGraphComponent = (props) => {
        useEffect(() => {
            props.getProductiveDay()
        }, [])
    
        return (
            <HorizontalBarGraph
                data={[2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3]}
                labels={["Sat", "Fri", "Thurs", "Wed", "Tues", "Mon", "Sun"]}
                width={Dimensions.get("window").width - 70}
                height={220}
                barRadius={2}
                barWidthPercentage={0.4}
                barColor="rgb(105, 126, 240)"
                baseConfig={{
                    hasYAxisBackgroundLines: false,
                    xAxisLabelStyle: {
                        rotation: 0,
                        fontSize: 13,
                        width: 60,
                        yOffset: 4,
                        xOffset: -12,
                    },
                    hasYAxisLabels: false,
                }}
                style={{
                    // marginLeft: 20,
                    marginRight: 60,
                    marginTop: -60,
                    padding: 10,
                    // borderWidth: 1,
                    // borderColor: "#EEEEEE",
                    borderRadius: 10,
                    width: Dimensions.get("window").width - 150,
                    // backgroundColor: `#FAFAFA`,
                }}
            />
        )
    }
    
    const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
        return {
            productiveDay: state.productiveDayReducer,
        }
    }
    
    const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
        return {
            getProductiveDay: () => dispatch(getProductiveDay()),
        }
    }
    
    export default connect(
        mapStateToProps,
        mapDispatchToProps
    )(HorizontalBarGraphComponent)
```

Comment: are you assing the value get from props.getProductiveDay() to data in HorizontalBarGraph

Comment: yes I did but I remove in and put in dummy data={[2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3]} so i didnt get the error

Comment: it's because props.getProductiveDay() not return an array

Comment: I am using redux I have just posted the rest of the code.... the action and the reducer

Answer (score 0):

this is the action ad the reducer for the question above

```
export const getProductiveDay = () => {
    return async (dispatch) => {
        const data = await AsyncStorage.getItem("productiveDay")
        const parse = JSON.parse(data)
        console.log("parse", parse)
        return dispatch({
            type: "FETCH_OVERALL_DISCIPLINE_LEVELS",
            data: parse,
        })
    }
}


const daysOfTheWeek = [
    {
        Monday: 1,
        Tuesday: 1,
        Wednesday: 1,
        Thursday: 1,
        Friday: 1,
        Saturday: 1,
        Sunday: 2,
    },
]


const productiveData = async (state) => {
    try {
        let json = JSON.stringify(state)
        await AsyncStorage.setItem("productiveDay", json)
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}


const productiveDayReducer = (state = daysOfTheWeek, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "FETCH_OVERALL_DISCIPLINE_LEVELS":
            
            return action.data
        case "INCREASE_PRODUCTIVITY":
            // state[day] += 1
            productiveData(state)
            return state
        case "DECREASE_PRODUCTIVITY":
            // state[day] -= 1
            productiveData(state)
            return state
        default:
            return state
    }
}

export default productiveDayReducer
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem react native and expo is quite cryptic with its error messages this took me so long to figure out but the problem was using combineReducers and two of the action types had the same string names...